# Python how to extend a list as if I was adding these items first time

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
question = []
question.append({'id' : 5, 'title' : 'First question', 'content' : 'Hi there'})

print("Question", question)

question.append({'username' : 'Ali'})

print("Question", question)
```

I would like to extend a list as if I was adding these items from stratch. The output of the print statement is:

> Question [{'id': 5, 'title': 'First question', 'content': 'Hi there'}, {'username': 'Ali'}]

How should I extend the list so that the print statement outputs this:

> Question [{'id': 5, 'title': 'First question', 'content': 'Hi there', 'username': 'Ali'}]

**Update:**
In the real example I tried three approaches. I got these error messages.

```
question[-1].update({'username' : 'Ali'})
```

> AttributeError: 'dict' object attribute 'update' is read-only

(I've also tried this before)

```
question["username"] = 'Ali'
```

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
question[0]["username"] = 'Ali'
```

works fine.

Comment: What happens if you replace `question.append({'username' : 'Ali'})` to `question[-1].update({'username' : 'Ali'})` ?

Comment: So why you need to use a list which just contains only one item?

Comment: @CristiFati thanks it works. Sraw in fact I'd like to add some records to MongoDB but I've shorten to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this for your query. Not sure if this solves your problem:

```
question = []
question.append({'id' : 5, 'title' : 'First question', 'content' : 'Hi there'})
question[0]["username"] = "test"
print question
```

Output:

```
[{'content': 'Hi there', 'username': 'test', 'id': 5, 'title': 'First question'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
question = {'id' : 5, 'title' : 'First question', 'content' : 'Hi there'}
# "extend" (=update the dictionary):

question['username'] = 'Ali'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of dictionaries:

```
dict_list = [{'foo': 'bar'}]
```

You're calling `dict_list.append`, which appends an item to the list

```
dict_list.append({'baz': 'bork'})
print dict_list # => [{'foo': 'bar'}, {'baz': 'bork'}]
```

If you want to update the original dictionary, then you should instead retrieve that specific dictionary, and then update that

```
dict_list = [{'foo': 'bar'}]
dict_list[0]['baz'] = 'bork' # we could also use dict_list[0].update here
print dict_list # => [{'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'bork'}]
```

That said, it looks like you're trying to build some kind of structure that holds these questions for easy retrieval. Rather than using a list for this, it might be more sensible to use a dict-of-dicts, where the key of each question was its id, something like:

```
questions = {}
questions[5] = {'title' : 'First question', 'content' : 'Hi there'}
questions[5]['username'] = 'Ali'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your purpose is adding a new field to your `object` but you are trying to append a new element `{'username' : 'Ali'}` to your `questions` list. So you should first add field `'username': 'Ali'` to your object then add this object to your `questions` list.

Hope this helps:

```
question = []
your_object = {'id' : 5, 'title' : 'First question', 'content' : 'Hi there'}
your_object['username'] = 'Ali'
question.append(your_object)

print("Question", question)
```

Comment: teşekkür ederim.

Comment: :) kolay gelsin hocam

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> question[0]["username"] = "Ali"
>>> print(question)
[{'username': 'Ali', 'id': 5, 'content': 'Hi there', 'title': 'First question'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing there is, actually adding a dictionary inside a list.

From what you have asked in the question you would like to add another variable to that dictionary so that it has a `username` key.

If thats what you want, following is a better way to do it.

```
question = {} #this will define the dictionary
question['id'] = 5
question['title'] = 'First question'
question['content'] = 'Hi there'
```

And then add the `username` value to that dictionary by

```
question['username'] = 'Ali'
```

Following line is also equivalent to the first 4 lines of the previous code

```
question = {'id' : 5, 'title' : 'First question', 'content' : 'Hi there'}
```

and then add the `username` key to the dictionary by `question['username'] = 'Ali`

---

To answer what you have asked, (which doesnt seem like the right way of doing things)

Now you have a list with single element which is dictionary, so to add values to the dictionary, you need to refer the first element of the list as follows

Instead of using `question.append({'username' : 'Ali'})` use `question[0]['username'] = 'Ali'`

What you did is actually added an element to the list `question` and hence the output was what you have mentioned.